# Repeating Endless Text Marquee

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, marquee

I'm looking for a clever and performant solution for a marquee effect (potentially with really using the marquee tag) to have some text within a container simply endlessly repeat.

What I'm trying to refer to is for instance this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="m-el">
    <marquee width="100%" direction="right">
    This text should endlessly be concatenated onto each other.
    </marquee>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.m-el { width: 1400px; }
```

I know there are a bunch of libraries for jquery out there that basically also emulate a marquee effect, but I wonder how this could potentially be done with the real marquee tag or maybe a css transition method.

Right now the effect produces this one line of text that is rolling through the parent div container: https://jsfiddle.net/8shjzdut/

I actually want to achieve that the text is basically "repeated" as endless loop like this but with the definition of only the sentence one time (without redundant pasting of the same text a 100 times) … https://jsfiddle.net/8shjzdut/1/

Any clever idea on how to do that? (if js is needed it's ok too, I just want it to be as performant and low-level as possible)

Comment: Note that the `<marquee>` tag is non-standard and has never been part of any HTML specification. It is listed in the current HTML5 spec for the sole purpose of flagging it as "obsolete" as notice that browser vendors intend to remove support at some time in the future. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: @Alohci *sigh* The specification says it--among others--"must not be used". Somewhere else, iirc, I believe it says browsers are not required to support obsolete features. While I shouldn't have said they intend to remove it, the intention of marking it as obsolete is pretty clear--especially for `<marquee>` which has never been part of any HTML specification.